# Define function without name and immediately call it

Tags: bash, shell-script, function, bash-functions

I have a script file (it's `.bashrc` actually), in this file I have a lot of variables and functions which are used only inside this script, but these variables and functions are publicly visible for any bash session. To avoid collisions, make me (as a shell user) to understand that this variables are internal and avoid unnecessary autocompletion I added a prefix `_bashrc_` for each variable and functions, e.g. `_bashrc_extensions`, but such prefixes looks ugly for me.

The idea I have in mind is to reduce scope of visibility to be able to remove these prefixes, but the only way I know in bash is to use `local` keyword, which can be used only inside a function. So I'm thinking about a function without a name which will be called immediately, something like this:

```
function {
  local path=$1
  # do something with $path
} "$HOME/.mypath"
```

Does something similar exist in bash?

Comment: No, but you can give it a name and then use `unset -f` to remove the name as the link provided by steeldriver suggests.

Comment: No, the  _name_ of the function is a required part of the [function declaration syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions). Zsh has [anonymous functions] though, not that you asked about it.

Comment: google `bash anonymous function`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299676/is-it-feasible-to-implement-anonymous-functions-in-bash-even-using-eval-if-nec